# Javascript multi-timer with editable number line

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, plot

I've written a quick timer script in jquery/javascript that allows my friend to time multiple events based on tags (for animal behavior research; i.e. mouse currently eating, mouse currently digging, etc), by just pressing any key, and it will keep track of time between keypresses and create a log.

In action here: http://jsbin.com/najexetu/1/edit?html,js,output (Just hit a..z keys to start timers)

My question is this: she wants a more intuitive, editable timeline, where it somehow puts editable boxes along a number line that represents the whole 1800 second video (like soundcloud comments, I imagine). I was going to make each key change print a new form input element where CSS puts it `seconds/1800*width` pixels from the left of the page, but that would make it difficult to keep the totals accurate if one is changed. Do any of you have ideas of how to make an editable timeline with easily retrieved values?

Thanks